# Web3j and Transaction with null receiver

Tags: java

I am trying to get the list of all transactions using the method `web3j.catchUpToLatestAndSubscribeToNewTransactionsObservable` but a lot of them have a null receiver (Transaction.to).

Using etherscan.io and the `tx hash` I can see that the receivers of those transactions are Contracts.

Example:

https://ropsten.etherscan.io/tx/0xea0b41af0ea0aa295cf1b42dc283ae3f276f58be4b9be0c1653765516c38fdb0

So is it correct to say that a transaction with null receiver is *always* a transaction to create or to interact with a smart contract?

Are there any other cases?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is it correct to say that a transaction with null receiver is always a transaction to create or to interact with a smart contract?

Sending a transaction to 0x0 is the special case for instantiating a new contract.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48219716/what-is-address0-in-solidity for more details.